# Internal Server Error - An internal server error occurred // SANITY // GATSBY

Tags: graphql, gatsby, sanity

community - can anyone tell me, why i'm getting this error message every time i try to deploy my sanity graphQl? (See image and code snippet).

```
u: Internal Server Error - An internal server error occurred
at onResponse (~/Documents/webdev/Zignifikant/Zignifikant/cms/node_modules/@sanity/cli/bin/sanity-cli.js:4504:497)
at ~/Documents/webdev/Zignifikant/Zignifikant/cms/node_modules/@sanity/cli/bin/sanity-cli.js:2820:241
at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
at ~/Documents/webdev/Zignifikant/Zignifikant/cms/node_modules/@sanity/cli/bin/sanity-cli.js:2820:225
at ~/Documents/webdev/Zignifikant/Zignifikant/cms/node_modules/@sanity/cli/bin/sanity-cli.js:2808:919
at ~/Documents/webdev/Zignifikant/Zignifikant/cms/node_modules/@sanity/cli/bin/sanity-cli.js:2808:1028
at x (~/Documents/webdev/Zignifikant/Zignifikant/cms/node_modules/@sanity/cli/bin/sanity-cli.js:2856:1442)
at ~/Documents/webdev/Zignifikant/Zignifikant/cms/node_modules/@sanity/cli/bin/sanity-cli.js:2856:2885
at u.<anonymous> (~/Documents/webdev/Zignifikant/Zignifikant/cms/node_modules/@sanity/cli/bin/sanity-cli.js:1554:181)
```

error Command failed with exit code 1.

[Image of my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4Sin.png)

Comment: The command tried to send an http request to the GraphQL API but an error/uncaught exceotion occured on the server-side and it therefore responded with a `500 Internal Server Error`.

Comment: Thank you very much @dan1st - you're a life saver!! I was logged out of my sanity account - and therefore the request could not be sent!

Comment: I was just reading your image - but an Internal server error does not seem like the appropriate response if you are not logged in. In any way, I am glad, I could help you.